# Using brackets with Harvard Referencing Style in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, harvard-style

I'm new to using LaTex. I'm trying to put references in the Harvard style. So far I have managed to get the reference right. Below is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{export}

\begin{document}
My Name is Mary \textcite{6824747}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

My export.bib file looks like this:

```
@online{6824747,
title = "Computational Modeling",
url = "http://www.nibib.nih.gov/science-education/science-topics/computational-modeling",
urldate = "2015-08-31",
year = "2013",
month = "07"
}
```

Below is how my reference looks like
[image]

**My question is how to include my reference with in brackets? For example My Name is Mary (*Computational* *Modeling* 2013)**.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\parencite` instead of `\textcite`.  In this particular case `\autocite` also works.  See the [`biblatex` documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex?lang=en) for the list of available citation commands.  The example below also demonstrates `\footcite`.

[image: Sample output top]

[image: Sample output bottom]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{export.bib}

\begin{document}
My Name is Mary \textcite{6824747}.

My Name is Mary \parencite{6824747}.

My Name is Mary \footcite{6824747}.

My Name is Mary \autocite{6824747}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```